# Alphabetize a string array without using Array.sort() or compareTo()?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, alphabetical

I have an exercise in class where you take names from the user and output them alphabetically. I'm not allowed to use `Array.sort()` or `compareTo()`. I seem to have gotten it to work for the most part... Except for when I enter something like `a aaa aa`, it outputs it in the following order:

```
aaa
aa
a
```

I'd really like to be able to output it in this order instead:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader key =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Alphabetizing names\n");

    System.out.println("Enter names separated by spaces:");
    StringTokenizer names1 = new StringTokenizer(key.readLine());

    int tokens = names1.countTokens();
    String[] names2 = new String[tokens];
    String y;

    for (int a = 0; a < tokens; a++) {

        names2[a] = names1.nextToken();

    }

    System.out.println("\nSorted names:");

    for (int a = 0; a < tokens; a++) {

        for (int b = a + 1; b < tokens; b++) {

            if(alphabetize(names2[a], names2[b])) {

                y = names2[a];
                names2[a] = names2[b];
                names2[b] = y;

            }

        }

    }

    for (int c = 0; c < tokens; c++) {

        System.out.println(names2[c]);

    }

}

static boolean alphabetize(String a, String b) {

    for(int c = 0; ; c++) {

        if((c == a.length()-1) && (c == b.length()-1)) {

            return false;

        }

        if(c == a.length()-1) {

            return true;

        }

        if(c == b.length()-1) {

            return false;

        }

        if((a.toLowerCase().charAt(c) - b.toLowerCase().charAt(c)) > 0) {

            return true;

        }

    }

}
```

Please help!! Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking at your code, but I can tell you that it has some problem also with other words

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: Look at the output.  What does it look like is happening?

Hint 2: Based on the obvious conclusion from Hint 1 ... look at the `alphabetize` method ... and figure out why that causes what you are seeing.

---

Meta-hint: I think your problem here is that you don't have a consistent mental model of what `alphabetize` is supposed to be doing; i.e. the intended meaning of the result.  There are two reasons for this:

1. The name of the method is opaque.  The word "alphabetize" is not a verb whose meaning maps to the action you are attempting to perform.  The http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alphabetize link says:

> ```
> alphabetize (ˈælfəbəˌtaɪz) or alphabetise. vb (tr)
> 1. to arrange in conventional alphabetical order
> 2. to express by an alphabet
> ```

Your method is doing neither of those things.

Yes ... method names **are** important.

2. You don't have any comments to explain what the method should return.  It is considered best practice to write a `javadoc` comment for any non-trivial method that forms the "contract" between the method and the code that calls the method.  In this case, you need a comment that says something like *"this method returns `true` if X, Y or Z, and `false` otherwise"*.

Comment: Great :-) i like answers that also try to reflect thinking (methodology)

Answer (score 0):

The problems are in alphabetizer:

1. **First if**: if a and b have the same length, you don't compare their last characters.
2. **Second and Third if**: if a and b have not the same length, you dont consider the last char of the shortest
3. **Fourth if**: you only consider the case where the char read from a is higher than the char read from b, you should also consider the case where b is higher than a.

Tip: The loop should continue only if the char that you read are equals,

---

Here how to solve your problem:

```
static boolean alphabetize(String a, String b) {
    char ca;
    char cb;
    for(int c = 0; ; c++) {
        ca = a.toLowerCase().charAt(c);
        cb = b.toLowerCase().charAt(c);
        if((c == a.length()-1) && (c == b.length()-1)) {
            return (ca - cb) > 0;
        } else if(c == a.length()-1) {
            return false;
        } else if(c == b.length()-1) {
            return true;
        } else if (ca - cb != 0) { //if are not equals
            return (ca - cb) > 0;
        }      
    }
}
```

I've tryed with many strings, for example this:

```
aaa ccc arc abr ald old mal ald aaaa bbbb aaaa car cro arc dsjd qhjk hdjgsdaj asidasiodu asi
```

Comment: I don't think that it is helpful to rewrite a beginner's code for him / her.  The chances are that he / she won't understand the code.  IMO, it is much better to help the beginner to solve the problem for him / herself.  That is harder to do ...

Comment: I didn't wanted to just rewrite code, indeed I was also writing an explaination of which were the problems. I think that knowing what is wrong and an example of a possible solution (if understood) can be constructive too. 
Anyway I agree with you and I really like your answer.
Thanks for your comment, I will consider it the next times.